# fatal: unable to access could not resolve host git lab ubuntu

Tags: git, clone, gitlab

I am trying to run git clone as below through Ubuntu terminal(unix) and getting below error..

```
git clone -c http.sslverify=false https://gitlab.financeexpert.com/finance/financeflow.git

error: fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.financeexpert.com/finance/financeflow.git': Could not resolve host: gitlab.financeexpert.com
```

In in friends laptop its working with the same command. He is using Windows 10 and I am using Windows11.

I tried disabling firewall , updating kernal and others but none  of the solution worked. Any suggestions pls
**** this host is an example one as we are under one VPN and unable to post the exact host due to security.

Comment: It can't be working elsewhere because the website doesn't exist.

Comment: @ChanganAuto : I am already using the website through browser.

Comment: I am not sure why negative vote comes here if a valid quesiton.

Comment: Valid questions with zero research and effort and with trivial error messages such as "Could not resolve host" tend to be downvoted. Invalid questions as in off-topic are closed and sometimes deleted (and can be downvoted as well meanwhile), therefore you shouldn't be surprised. Again and for the last time the site doesn't exist, domain neither and everything else Google reports suggests SCAM (no surprise there either). Tested with several different ISPs, VPNs and even TOR. What you may be seeing is a cached page, or you're mistaken  or trolling.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I am unable to post the exact host due to security and the host which i works under VPN. As i am posting a generic error and i am trying to have suggestions from someone which has similar issue and if they have done any changes in their system. Not sure whats wrong with the question. Pls ignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that site is working on a different computer it is because there is software on that other computer that is malicious, poisoning DNS entries on that computer so that the malicious website appears to use that domain name.

The other person should resolve the malware problems on their computer.

The error is clear and others have confirmed: that site does not exist on the real internet at the address you've given.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inputs. We are under one VPN and sorry for not able to give an exact name. But when i am trying from Windows 10 through Ubuntu terminal i am able to connect and clone it. But When i am trying the same from Windows11 somehow its blocking. If i am using Windows Command Prompt i am able to clone it but when i am when through Bash and run the same command : i am getting this error. Any suggestion pls

Comment: @Arya - it would be better to add this information to your question and not in the comments. That way people can see all of the information in one place, rather than having to read all of the answers and comments as well in order to get the complete picture.